# How to open native phone app android - phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, native

I've made an android app with phonegap - cordova. I need to open the native phone app with a number. What can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at the webintent plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer but hope that it'll help someone. Suppose your phone number is 411

```
<button onclick="document.location='tel:411'">Phone</button>
```

Comment: @candlejack Please do not edit the meaning of answers. Rather, leave a comment or add another answer.